# Use the result of a method as a parameter inside another method

Tags: c#

I'd like to take the result of a method and use the result of that in a parameter inside another function.

Example:

```
 public static async Task<string> GetToken(string User, string Pass)
        {
          //do stuff
         return token;
        }
 public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> Auth()
        {
          AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", GetToken());
         }
```

Obviously not a working example, but hopefully it gets the point across. GetToken is taking command line arguments, hence the need for the User+Pass strings.

Comment: `await GetToken()`?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: If GetToken() takes parameters (User+Pass) will that work?

Comment: Well, if GetToken takes user and pass, you have to pass in user and pass, or you need to call GetToken elsewhere and pass the result into Auth.

Answer (score 2):

you should use `await` keyword

```
public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> Auth()
{
    var token = await GetToken('username' , 'password');
    AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
}
```

Comment: Or use await inline; `AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetToken(...));`

Comment: So if GetToken requires user+pass, and in order to use it in the other method, wouldn't I also have to define that in the method? e.g. `Auth(string User, string Pass)`?

Comment: This not answer OP's question